# Trans-log production function or trans-log cost function

Tags: microeconomics, elasticity

I'm researching to analyze the elasticity of substitution between factors of production. From what I've read, many researchers use the trans-log production and cost functions. Which function should I use, considering I want to analyze the data at the sectoral level?

Answer (score 1):

There is no one right answer. Consider using several types of production functions, for robustness. The most popular tend to be Cobb-Douglas and Translog functions.